# How to centre two columns with buttons in them in a row of bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am working on aligning two buttons in the centre of a row in bootstrap. I have put the two buttons in two columns and this column in a single large column to centre all items. It is centring but stacking on top of each other. 
I want the buttons to be aligned side by side in the centre of the row as shown in this image: [Image showing desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obrTW.jpg)

Here is my code:

```css
.con
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid con">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 mx-auto">
            <div class="col-sm-6 mx-auto">
                <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                    Sign Up
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 mx-auto">
                <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                    Log in
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

I searched the stackoverflow for possible answers but in my search didnot come across the answer. If the answer is already answered and you know about it, please direct me to it.

Comment: inside row class div, add another div occupying 1/4th space with col-sm-3 and change remaining two divs with button to col-sm-3 and remove column class enclosing them

Comment: https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ZwwzrO

Comment: I am getting this : https://imgur.com/R3aoX9L
but I want this : https://imgur.com/GFlv3xL

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option

1. Inside row class div, use 4 columns with middle two columns having divs with buttons i.e with class - **col-sm-3**
2. Removing div with class - col-lg-4 mx-auto, to center button divs inside row class div

```css
.con
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid con">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 mx-auto"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 mx-auto">
            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                Sign Up
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 mx-auto">
            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                Log in
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ZwwzrO

Comment: can I get this : https://imgur.com/GFlv3xL ? side by side with no space in between in the center.

Comment: got it by using the offset class
https://codepen.io/pushkalsingh/pen/bzzGNV

Comment: or you can divide row to two columns and text-align right content of first column - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/OddJLL

Answer (score 0):

I would use .off-set class to margin the divs and then text-center class to center buttons inside div elements. You can also play with the widths of cols but I believe you get the idea.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2 offset-4 text-center">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                  Sign Up
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 text-center">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                  Log in
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

**Pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YBBKQL**

Comment: can I get this : https://imgur.com/GFlv3xL 
side by side at the center with no space in between.

Comment: got it by adding changing your code : 
https://codepen.io/pushkalsingh/pen/bzzGNV
thanks

Comment: Happy to help! I do now understand what you wanted. You will get the same result even when you use `<div class="col-12 text-center">` It then depends on your preference on responsibility. But in this specific case the behaviour should be the same.

Comment: Haha, responsibility is probably not the correct word. Sorry about that. You know what I mean.

Comment: yes I got your idea...and also the code ..thanks for help

Comment: Always happy to help